# How do i download a file in the existing format from the server using angular-file-saver?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, filesaver.js

I have used angular-file-saver to download a file in my application but I'm stuck with,how i can implement the same while downloading from the server and saving the file in the existing form.

My controller.js

```
vm.download = function(data){
 vm.ProjectId = workspaceService.getSelectedWorkSpaceDeal().id;
 manageRFPService.getFieldData(vm.ProjectId).then(function(data){
 vm.downloading = data;
 var down = new Blob([vm.downloading],{ type: 'text/plain;charset=utf-8' });
 FileSaver.saveAs(down,'documentname.txt');
 }); };
```

the response in the data contains a file name but the file is not downloading with its extension rather just an response is getting downloaded in text form.

my Html

```
<td><a ng-href=" " ng-click="vm.download( )">{{uploading.documentname}}</a>
```

If the above getting response is similar for multiple object display

Comment: i can see in the marked existing question response type is "responseType: 'blob' "....instead of using as such can we use a blob as creating object instance above....because im using the same get response for other instances in application too...? @georgeawg

Comment: [A Blob object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) can be used wherever a URL is used: `href`, `src`, `window.open`,etc. To manipulate it in JavaScript, use the [FileReader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) to convert it to an arraybuffer, base64, or text.

Comment: Thank you..:)...i was able to solve that..@georgeawg